# Python - Fastest way to generate list of random colours with fixed alpha

Tags: python, performance, random, numpy, colors

So I'm looking to generate a large list of approximately 332 million colours (tuples with 4 values - r,g,b,a) in Python, but with a fixed alpha value of 0.6. I also need to duplicate every colour in the row below it (i.e. I end up with 664 million rows - only 332 million distinct colours.

I have tried and tested many methods but have concluded the fastest so far is to use numpy to:

1. Create an array of length 332 million containing 3 random float values per row using numpy random
2. Create a second array of the same length with the values [0, 0, 0, 0.6] per row using numpy tile
3. Copy the values from the first array into the first 3 values per row of the second array
4. Use the numpy repeat function to repeat every row onto a new inserted row below (interleave the array with duplicates of the previous row)

The code for this takes approx. 574 seconds or 10 minutes and is:

```
import time
import numpy as np

t1 = time.time()

randomnos = np.random.random_sample((332000000, 3)) 
trans = np.tile([0,0,0,0.6],(332000000, 1))
trans[:,:-1] = randomnos
colorarray = np.repeat(trans, 2, axis=0)

t2 = time.time()

totaltime = t2 - t1

print "Time Taken = %f seconds" % totaltime
```

Now as I don't need to generate the random numbers at runtime I concluded that I could just run this code once and save to file (using numpy save), then read the file at runtime using the numpy load function, however even though this is considerably faster it is still too slow for me taking 106 seconds or approximately 2 minutes.

I think there must be a faster way to generate random colours at runtime?

The desired output is something like:

```
array = [[ 0.98112321  0.38567094  0.2430455   0.6       ]
 [ 0.98112321  0.38567094  0.2430455   0.6       ]
 [ 0.54728619  0.97823465  0.86675383  0.6       ]
 [ 0.54728619  0.97823465  0.86675383  0.6       ]
 ..., 
 [ 0.15047076  0.55844066  0.79842858  0.6       ]
 [ 0.15047076  0.55844066  0.79842858  0.6       ]
 [ 0.53637406  0.52150776  0.44890727  0.6       ]
 [ 0.53637406  0.52150776  0.44890727  0.6       ]]
```

Comment: If you want to read from a file: try `pickle` or `cpickle`. Or use a small database like sqlite.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I have tried pickle and numpy load was faster (colours are saved in a binary format) also from experience even an sql database is slow to retrieve this many rows so I don't think it would be any faster, and ideally I'd like to steer away from having to store it in a database due to the additional overhead.

Comment: How many bits of rgb can your colors hold? There are only 16,777,216 24bit colors so enumerating may be quicker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm a bit confused by the code you've shown.  You seem to be doing things in a very round-about way, and I may be misunderstanding exactly what you want.

However, as I understand it, you want:

```
import numpy as np

colorarray = np.random.random_sample((332000000, 4))
colorarray[:, -1] = 0.6
colorarray = np.vstack([colorarray, colorarray])
```

This takes ~30 seconds for me.

Or, if you wanted to optimize things as much as possible, you can shave off a second or two:

```
num = 332000000
colorarray = np.empty((2 * num, 4), dtype=float)
colorarray[:num, :3] = np.random.random_sample((num, 3))
colorarray[:num, -1] = 0.6
colorarray[num:] = colorarray[:num]
```

This takes ~28 seconds.

---

*Edit*: I completely misunderstood what you wanted to do.  (My fault, not yours. You had a nice, stand-alone, runnable example. I just didn't read closely enough!)

To "interleave" the values, we can use a simple slicing trick.  Starting with the more optimized example:

```
num = 332000000
colorarray = np.empty((2 * num, 4), dtype=float)
colorarray[::2, :3] = np.random.random_sample((num, 3))
colorarray[::2, -1] = 0.6
colorarray[1::2] = colorarray[::2]
```

This takes a bit longer to run (~42 seconds), but gives the values you want.

`numpy.repeat`, as you were originally using, actually turns out to be a bit faster than assigning to slices, in this case.  Therefore, we can get things down to ~34 seconds with:

```
colorarray = np.empty((num, 4), dtype=float)
colorarray[:, :3] = np.random.random_sample((num, 3))
colorarray[:, -1] = 0.6
colorarray = np.repeat(colorarray, 2, axis=0)
```

**Edit 2**

And at the end of all this, I finally though to benchmark your original code... It's actually almost identical in speed to my final version.  It seems like my comment on your example being "roundabout" was completely off-base!

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I timed your optimized solution and it took 106 seconds, so it is faster than reading from file. But is there no faster way to do this?

Comment: As for you're confusion perhaps if I explain the background it may help. So basically these colours are used for an OpenGL draw line function, but as the vertices for the lines are stored in the VBO and there are two vertices per line, OpenGL requires the same length colour VBO and thus two colours per line. I require all lines to have the same transparency hence the fixed alpha of 0.6, and as I want the lines to be coloured as differently as possible I require the random function to create the RGB float values.

Comment: Well, the bottleneck is in generating random values.  If you're okay with non random, but probably different values, you could use a few other options (e.g. initialize the array using whatever happens to be in memory and then rescale it to a 0-1 range).  I'll add a couple of other examples in a bit.

Comment: Okay thanks, also I saw your edit and I guess you right about the round about way, the reason being because I tried a more compact way but it didn't give me the output I desired. As for your timings, may I ask what are your system specs? Just because I have a very powerful laptop (Upgraded MacBook Pro Retina), and so your machine must be extremely powerful?

Comment: Also I just checked the output of your optimised solution and I guess I have confused you about my desired output. It seems that in your solution I don't have the duplicate rows I require, I'll edit my question to add an example of the desired output.

Comment: @JamesElder - Ah! Your code makes more sense now! I ran it, but somehow missed the "interleaving" in the output.  Yes, there's an efficient way to do that as well. Just a bit and I'll add an updated example.  (As for the machine, yes, it's fast, but it probably has more to do with memory speed than CPU speed.)

Comment: I also just realised that now I took time to understand your optimised code without the interleaving, that I had the same code previously but because it was extremely slow (hangs on my machine) I did not pursue why it wasn't performing the interleaving that I require...

Comment: Okay so just to clarify in case anyone else is requiring something similar. The method using slicing in the edit, hangs on my machine and so I cannot say it work's faster than the method in my question. The method using numpy repeat in the edit, takes the same time as the method I posted on my machine.

Comment: Also just wanted to say I was repeating the rows 14 times in the interleaving, as opposed to 2 'colorarray = np.repeat(colorarray, 14, axis=0)' (as I was just simplifying to 2 for the sake of the question) and this is why I said 574 seconds. To duplicate rows only once my code takes a similar time to the 34 seconds you say.